# Apache sqoop incremental saved jobs setting

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

With saved jobs using sqoop, the ooficial doc states that newer records will be imported. No issue with that.

But, what if we want to use saved jobs and we want to use >= last saved value, e.g. timestamp inaccuracies that can occur with this data type in a concurrent usage database? Can we influence the saved value or the comparison, i.e >= instead of > ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also tried using the incremental uploads using Sqoop jobs based on last timestamp. The challenge you would face is if the Sqoop service restarts, it looses the track of timestamp or the control variable you are using.

I would recommend to tweak the import query instead. For example if you want to incremental import for `table_1` from RDBMS to Hive, use something in `bash shell` like this:

```
    # Get the max id from the hive table
    maxCount=`hive -S -e "SELECT MAX(id) FROM hivedb.table_1" | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f1`

    # If maxCount is not a number, make it zero.
    re='^[0-9]+$'
    if ! [[ $maxCount =~ $re ]] ; then
       maxCount=0
    fi

    # Build the SQL query
    sql_query="select col1, col2, ..., coln from  table_1 (NOLOCK) WHERE id > ${maxCount}"

    # Run the Sqoop import
    sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:jdbcUrl;UserName=usrname;password=password;database=dbName' --query "$sql_query AND \$CONDITIONS" -m 4 --split-by id --hive-table hivedb.table_1 --hive-import ;
```

Comment: Confirms my view as being touchy, thx. But from a different perspective.